# Jenkins Build Failing - ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, openshift

I am trying to get jenkins to build my core code base and am having some difficulties with what appears to be the final stage of it.

The application seems to process fine in Jenkins until the final step - this is in the console output below

```
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Core ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Core ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Core ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3:jar (default-jar) @ Core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/Core-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Core ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/Core-1.0.jar to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/.m2/repository/Core/Core/1.0/Core-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/pom.xml to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/.m2/repository/Core/Core/1.0/Core-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.989 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T09:18:32-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/345M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parsing POMs
[secondstory_core] $ /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/bin/mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Core 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Core ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Core ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Core ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Core ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Core ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3:jar (default-jar) @ Core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/Core-1.0.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Core ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/target/Core-1.0.jar to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/.m2/repository/Core/Core/1.0/Core-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/app-root/data/workspace/secondstory_core/pom.xml to /var/lib/openshift/53c9065f5973ca9d1b0001e8/.m2/repository/Core/Core/1.0/Core-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.735 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-18T09:19:18-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler$AcceptorImpl.<init>(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:178)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler.call(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:164)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory$SocketHandler.call(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:162)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:235)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:749)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:585)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1684)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Sending e-mails to: builds@secondstory.co.uk
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see - I am getting a couple of success messages until finally a Build Failed - giving the error

> java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Does anyone know what configuration (or lack of) I have that might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: What was the goal you are trying to build? Apparently something after `install`, maybe `deploy`? Are this two goals, like `install deploy`? Also does this work locally?

Comment: @Fabian i am using clean install as my goals

Comment: Ah yes. Now I see it. It appears that maven finished succesfully and something fails afterwards. Please have a look at your post build actions, maybe something is wrong there. I guess its the "send email" part, unless you are getting the mails?

Comment: I am getting the emails without any issue. I think it might be failing to connect yo the open shift platform?

Comment: That may be the case, unfortunately I have not used openshift yet. I can from now on only give general ideas: Security manager / firewall preventing jenkins from opening port? Try to find a better error log or increase debugging information.

Comment: Looks like https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/jenkins-failed-to-build-maven-project, doesn't it?